# dropping beginning of line off edits

Tags: bug, edits

On this post [Google Search Console: Fetch-and-Render fails on random resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593129/google-search-console-fetch-and-render-fails-on-random-resources)

I included "Hi @jeron-diovis, you..." to the beginning of an answer... it dropped the "Hi @jeron-"

I then edited it to just include Hi jeron-diovis, you..." same result

So I tried just "Hi," and that removed the "Hi," and just left the rest of the line from "you..." onwards

So I gave up. What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [We now automatically remove salutations from posts as they are entered.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/288751)

Answer (score 1):

this first line is intended to demonstrate the effects since I included a similar section when writing.

I suspect that the system is *purposefully* removing that text from your answer, since a prelude like that is generally considered unprofessional and is [acceptable for others to remove](/q/260776/6388243).

Comment: As predicted, the leading "hi" was removed.

Comment: interesting, since SE is moving to a more welcoming approach, especially with new members.

Comment: @garth Even with the new CoC, there's still a rule to "be professional".

Comment: hardly see this as unprofessional - in business it would be considered just the opposite. it's def not the case with other SE properties

Comment: @garth there's also the fact that the site was, and still is, designed to maximize the signal-to-noise ratio. Either way, removing that stuff from answers is definitely something intentional, whether it's outdated or not.

Comment: @garth noise is still noise. Salutations have nothing to do with being welcoming.

Comment: @garth: The idea of Stack Overflow is to build Q&A pairs that are useful for future visitors. Addressing the OP in an answer directly is therefore inappropriate, because the answer should be for all visitors and not look like part of a private discussion with the OP.

Comment: @TinyGiant good to know, it's amazing that I and my generation have been wrong for so long about this. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: @honk thanks. this is the first good explanation as to why salutations may be undesirable, especially given the oft poor (ie. caustic / rude) responses that were common in tech properties of SE in the past few years. Hence why lots of people like myself took a break from it.

Comment: @Garth glad I could be of service.